# docker-compose secrets not being bonded/read by environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, docker-secrets

I am try to use secrets(from file - db_password.txt - content: root) in docker-compose.

->docker-compose -f compose-prod-replicaset.yml up --build --force-recreate

The secret is being mounted in "run/secrets/db_password" folder, normally; See that:

```
[0m total 8
[0m drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 22 19:34 .
[0m drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 22 19:34 ..
[0m -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 22 17:24 db_password
```

However, when I have tried to use this secret as a environmental variable(db_password), the secret is being as its secret's path, in *"plain text"*(run/secrets/db_password);

My versions are:

- Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086
- docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

I have used the docker-compose to create a mongodb uri, as you can see the **username** is "root", BUT the **password** is being bind as ***"run/secrets/db_password"***. For example:

- mongodb://root:**run/secrets/db_password**@mongo1:27017/devtestdb?authSource=admin

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  api-net:

services:
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:4.4.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - api-net
    volumes:
      - ./db-test:/data/db

  api:
    container_name: api
    image: pauloportfolio/api
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: target/*.jar
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./db-test:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
    networks:
      - api-net
    secrets:
      - db_password
    environment:
      HOST_DB: mongo1
      PORT_DB: 27017
      AUTH_DB: admin
      STD_DB: devtestdb
      STD_USER: root
      PASS_FILE: run/secrets/db_password
      PORT_API: 8080
      DEBUG_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -Xmx1G -Xms128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m

secrets:
  db_password:
    file: ./db_password.txt
```

Please, any help is useful.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is all behaving as expected. You need to read the secret value from the specified file.

Comment: @larsks  Thanks, for the fast answer. However, it is not being gotten "the context of the file"(root), instead it is being using the "secret-path" as a plain-text. Do you have some suggesiton in order to solve that?

Comment: Yep.. you can find my solution here: https://github.com/codegtd/spring-webflux-replicaset

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a secrets file into an environment variable, the [Official MySQL Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) has a solution for you.

See `docker_setup_env()` and `file_env()` functions in [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh)

e.g. -

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql-root -d mysql:tag
```

Results in loading the contents of `/run/secrets/mysql-root` into `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`

Comment: the question is not about MySQL

Answer (score -2):

Might I recommend using an `.env` file with docker-compose:

> You can set default values for environment variables using a `.env` file, which Compose automatically looks for in project directory (parent folder of your Compose file). - [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files)

```
# .env
MONGODB_PASSWORD=abc123
```

Then, you can [pass the variable to the container](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers).

```
# docker-compose.yml
...
services:
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:4.4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=$MONGODB_PASSWORD
    restart: always
...
```

In your code, you will need to reference the `${MONGODB_PASSWORD}` environment variable.